# questions regarding one code segment, maybe related to datetime function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There is code segment,

```
start = datetime.datetime.strptime("1973-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
date_list = [start + relativedelta(months=x) for x in range(0,115)]
```

The print out of date_list looks like as follows:

```
datetime.datetime(1973, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1973, 2, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1973, 3, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1973, 4, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1973, 5, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1973, 6, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1973, 7, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1973, 8, 1, 0, 0),
```

Afterwards, there has

```
df['index']=date_list
df.set_index(['index'], inplace=True)
df.index.name=None
```

However, the printout of `df` looks like as follows, which confuses me is that the index of `df` is like `1973-03-01`, while, the original date_list looks like `datetime.datetime(1973,3,1,0,0)`. Which part of the code causes this change.

[image]

Comment: Please add all associated module imports to your code so we can run it. Thanks.

Comment: Pandas does not show by default datetime obj in a data frame as `datetime.datetime(...)`, it shows as `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of brevity and readability, would you be happier if you saw `datetime.datetime(1973,3,1,0,0)` as opposed to `1973-03-01`? On creation of DataFrame pandas may coerce date type to `pd.Timestamp`, maybe that what happens `df.set_index()` command. You can alsways check what your `df.index` is, too.

My personal take is that `datetime.datetime(1973,3,1,0,0)` are a bit ugly and `1973-03-01` are much nicer. if you are hungry for `datetime`, `datetime.date` is a bit more concise as you seem to work with dates only, not times.